# Introducing ToolTips in a CGI python Form

Tags: python, cgi

I have a CGI form in python and i would like to introduce in this form a tooltip
containing indications on the value that has to be written in a field when this
field in focused.

My form is the following :

```
print '<form name="input" action="operation.py" method="get">'
print '<input type="submit" value="Submit">'
print '<table>'
print '<tr><td>%s</td><td><input type="text" name=%s size="100" value=%s></td></tr>' %('test','test', 'test')
print '<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td></td></tr>'
print '</table>'

print '<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>'
print '</body></html>'
```

so how can introduce a tooltip for the field test ?

Thank you
Ismail

Comment: Have you consider to use the HTML5 [`placehoder`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use the title attribute as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp).

```
<td title="Use this for something">
```

Comment: I prefere to use HTML4 title attribute as shown below, thank you for your answers.